# In Flink, stream windowing does not seem to work?

Tags: apache-flink

I tried to enhance the Flink example displaying the usage of streams. 
My goal is to use the windowing features (see the `window` function call).
I assume that the code below outputs the sum of last 3 numbers of the stream.
(the stream is opened thanks to `nc -lk 9999` on ubuntu)
Actually, the output sums up ALL numbers entered. Switching to a time window produces the same result, i.e. no windowing produced.

Is that a bug? (version used: latest master on github )

```scala
object SocketTextStreamWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val hostName = args(0)
    val port = args(1).toInt
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    // Create streams for names and ages by mapping the inputs to the corresponding objects
    val text = env.socketTextStream(hostName, port)    
    val currentMap = text.flatMap { (x:String) => x.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }
    .filter { (x:String) => x.nonEmpty }      
    .window(Count.of(3)).every(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    //  .window(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).every(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      .map { (x:String) => ("not used; just to have a tuple for the sum", x.toInt) }

    val numberOfItems = currentMap.count
    numberOfItems print
    val counts = currentMap.sum( 1 )
    counts print

    env.execute("Scala SocketTextStreamWordCount Example")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is an implicit conversion from `WindowedDataStream` to `DataStream`. This implicit conversion calls `flatten()` on the `WindowedDataStream`.

What happens in your case is that the code gets expanded to this:

```scala
val currentMap = text.flatMap { (x:String) => x.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }
    .filter { (x:String) => x.nonEmpty }      
    .window(Count.of(3)).every(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .flatten()   
    .map { (x:String) => ("not used; just to have a tuple for the sum",x.toInt) }
```

What `flatten()` does is similar to a `flatMap()` on a collection. It takes the stream of windows which can be seen as a collection of collections (`[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]`) and turns it into a stream of elements: `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

This means that your count really operates only on the original stream that has been windowed and "de-windowed". This looks like it has never been windowed at all.

This is a problem and I will work on fixing this right away. (I'm one of the Flink committers.) You can track the progress here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2096

The way to do it with the current API is this:

```scala
val currentMap = text.flatMap { (x:String) => x.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }
    .filter { (x:String) => x.nonEmpty }   
    .map { (x:String) => ("not used; just to have a tuple for the sum",x.toInt) }    
    .window(Count.of(3)).every(Time.of(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

`WindowedDataStream` has a sum() method so there will be no implicit insertion of the flatten() call. Unfortunately, `count()` is not available on `WindowedDataStream` so for this you have to manually add a `1` field to the tuple and count these.

Comment: Then, with current API, what would be the correction to apply on the example code?